# While running the tests, cypress is redirecting

Tags: cypress, cypress-file-upload

while I am running the tests in cypress, it is redirecting to login page, then remaining tests become fails . What is the reason for that

Comment: If your application requires a login, then it should also be performed similar in tests with a test user. What kind of login does your app use?

Answer (score 0):

If the login page in your tests contains another domain - cypress fails the test and stop the scenario.
Here link: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Limitations